# Checking for presence of a key within an S3 object

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

So my S3 structure looks like this:

```
Bucket 
|
|--------/print-objects
                  |
                  |
              /20190417
                  |
                  |
               image-file.png
```

I need to check if the /20190417 "date" key exists, and if it doesn't, to create this key.

```
export function checkDateKeyExists(bucketName: string, key: string, dateKey: string) {
  const s3 = new aws.S3({ params: { Bucket: bucketName, Delimiter: '/', Prefix: 'print-objects/' } });
  const params: aws.S3.Types.GetObjectRequest = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: key }
  s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      log.debug("Error:", err)
    } else {
      log.debug("Data:", data)
      const s3DateKey = Object.keys(data).filter((dateKey) => dateKey.slice(0, 13) == 'print-objects')
      log.error(s3DateKey)
    }
  })
```

I seem to be having trouble drilling down to the nested date key, and am unable to check whether or not it exists.

I'm getting the following `data` back:

```
 Data: 
{
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2019-07-04T18:30:12.000Z,
  ContentLength: 0,
  ETag: '"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"',
  ContentType: 'application/x-directory',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer >
} +0ms
```

When I return the contents of `Object.keys(data)` I get an array of metadata keys (I think  this is for the `print-objects` Object itself), as opposed to the date key nested within the print object.

```
[
  'AcceptRanges',
  'LastModified',
  'ContentLength',
  'ETag',
  'ContentType',
  'Metadata',
  'Body'
] +1ms
```

Comment: Your description says it is at /print-object but you are looking for print-objects plural. Is that a typo? What is the value of Object.keys(data)?

Comment: I apologize - yes, that was a typo

Comment: Note: In s3 if a path does not exist it creates the path or if it exist it overrides the file in the path when you post the data again. So do you expect not to override the file in the path ?

Comment: S3 has no idea of directories; prefixes are arbitrary and do not exist separately from objects. Why aren't you asking S3 _directly_ about `Prefix: 'print-objects/20190417/'`? If a non-empty list of keys is returned, something exists under that prefix.

Comment: Ok so from the looks of it you do not have a date key in the data.  If you just want to look for and add key if it doesn't exist you can use this code: `('date' in data) || (data.date=<insert your formatted date here>)`  Which will basically run the second statement if the first does not evaluate to true.

Comment: @kaarthickraman I didn't realize this... that actually solves my whole problem!